# How Sending multiple emails with PHPmailer

Tags: php, email, phpmailer

I have thousands of emails and I want to send an e-mail to all of them and I can not solve it. Is anyone able to help and clarify with examples in ways of solving

As shown in the following code what is the problem and what is the solution

```
$mail->isSMTP();                              // Set mailer to use SMTP
    $mail->Host = 'gator4164.hostgator.com '; // Specify main and backup SMTP servers
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;                   // Enable SMTP authentication
    $mail->Username   = "...";                // SMTP username
    $mail->Password = '...';                  // SMTP password
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';                // Enable TLS encryption, `ssl` also accepted
    $mail->Port = 465;                        // TCP port to connect to
    $mail->CharSet = 'UTF-8';
    $get = new get();
    $getEmails = $get->getEmails();
    $CountEmails = $get->CountEmails();

    $mail->setFrom('email@gmail.com', 'Email Name');

    foreach($getEmails as $getEmails){

        for ($x = $emails['id']; $x <= $CountEmails; $x++) {
            $mail->addAddress($emails['email'],$emails['name']);
            $mail->isHTML(true);              // Set email format to HTML
                $mail->Subject = $title;

                $mail->Body    = nl2br($content);

                $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

      }
      if(!$mail->send()) {
          echo 'Message could not be sent.';
          echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
      } else {
          echo'<div class="done">Done</div>';

      }
    }
```

Comment: Take a look at [the mailing list example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/mailing_list.phps), and also the [sending to lists article](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Sending-to-lists) in the wiki.

Answer (score 1):

For such kind of scenario, you have to create a `Process Queue` because every email sending needs some time to process and if the email count is thousand then in that case your system will crash as it is having a processing time limit. For creating a process queue you have to maintain a database table in which save all the records and maintain a status with different values like:

```
0: Initial, 1:Processing, 2: Email Sent
```

And create a separate functionality that pick a record on a regular interval and send the email and change the status. Put this functionality on CRON.

Comment: I think your solution is good but can you explain this solution with code so I can understand more and help me more

Answer (score 0):

Don't add all of the recipients with "add" in one loop then you have one Email with all recipients. Send your E-Mail with every duration.

```
foreach($getEmails as $getEmails){
    $emails['email'] = $getEmails['email'];
    $emails['name']  = $getEmails['name'];

    $mail->addAddress($emails['email'],$emails['name']);
    $mail->isHTML(true);                                  // Set email format to HTML
    $mail->Subject = $title;
    $mail->Body    = nl2br($content);
    $mail->AltBody = 'This is the body in plain text for non-HTML mail clients';

    if(!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Message could not be sent.';
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo'Email send to ' + $emails['email'];
    }
    $mail->clearAddresses();
}
```

something like this. So send the Email for every duration. To prevent that you send people duplicate emails you should set the status in your database if the email is send otherwise you send it again if you have an error in your script and you have to restart the script.

Comment: This only ever *adds* addresses, so the first message will send to the first recipient, the second to the first *and* second, third to all 3 and so on. You must use the `clearAddresses()` method at the end of the loop to clear them out. Also you're not using SMTP & keepalive so it will be slow - see the links I added to the Q.

Comment: Sorry i've used the given code. I've added the line.